# Поправить условие на php

Tags: php, url, условия

Подскажите,где ошибка и как поправить?
Хочу сделать так,чтобы при совпадении с указанным url выводилось одно, при других остальных случаях другое.

```
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($uri == 'ссылка' or $uri == '/') echo '$res .= '<div class="col-md-2"><a title="' . $item['name'] . '"' . (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],trim($item['url'],'\t\n\r\0\x0B')) == 0 ? ' href="ссылка' . $item['url'] . '/"' : '') . ' class="tabs-cell ' . (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],trim($item['url'],'\t\n\r\0\x0B')) != 0 ? 't-cur' : '') . ' ' . ($item['id'] == 248 || $item['id'] == 249 ? 't-mods' : '') . '">
            <img src="ссылка' . $item['url'] . '.png" alt="' . $item['name'] . '">
            <div itemprop="name" class="category-tabs--title">' . $par['title_tabs'] . '</div></div></a>';
    }
    $res .= '</div></div>';

    return $res;';
else echo '$res .= '<div class="col-md-6"><a title="' . $item['name'] . '"' . (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],trim($item['url'],'\t\n\r\0\x0B')) == 0 ? ' href="ссылка' . $item['url'] . '/"' : '') . ' class="tabs-cell ' . (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],trim($item['url'],'\t\n\r\0\x0B')) != 0 ? 't-cur' : '') . ' ' . ($item['id'] == 248 || $item['id'] == 249 ? 't-mods' : '') . '">
            <img src="ссылка' . $item['url'] . '.png" alt="' . $item['name'] . '">
            <div itemprop="name" class="category-tabs--title">' . $par['title_tabs'] . '</div></div></a>';
    }
    $res .= '</div></div>';

    return $res;';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще сказать в какой строке нет ошибки.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(($uri == 'ссылка') or ($uri == '/'))
{
  echo 'Текст если условие верно';
} else 
{
   echo 'Текст иначе';
}
```

Дальше вставляете нужные вам данные.
Вариант с переменной

```
$res = (isset($res) ? $res : '');
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(($uri == 'ссылка') or ($uri == '/'))
{
  $res .= 'Текст если условие верно';
} else 
{
  $res .= 'Текст иначе';
}
$res .= 'Окончание идиентичное для обоих случаев.';
echo $res.'тут можно еще текст добавить'."<br>\r\n".
"А в таких кавычках можно использовать переменные например <pre>$res</pre>";
```

Comment: Мне кажется оно так работать не будет. https://jsfiddle.net/1u6tma52/

Comment: C чего бы оно не работало?
https://yadi.sk/i/o8TR2KRfUU8iDQ

Comment: С моим кодом оно не будет работать, т.к. там присутствуют переменные и апострофы. Как в echo добавить мой код? Который начинается с '$res

Comment: Ваш код и сам по себе не будет работать, исправлять ваш код к сожалению почти не реально в том виде в котором он есть, отформатируйте его нормально и тогда я укажу на ошибки именно в вашем коде, сейчас он не читаем. Поправил пример, добавил переменную.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен. Отформатировал https://jsfiddle.net/1u6tma52/4/   и скриншот https://i99.fastpic.ru/big/2018/0918/d3/8d132fdf1fac511e7239c6c1a6b4cbd3.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1u6tma52/8/

Comment: спасибо разобрался))